# Hide cut/paste panel from keyboard in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

How to remove the panel that contains copy/cut/paste button from the keyboard from iOS 9.

I don't want to show any panel or the keyboard suggestion.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
yourTextField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
yourTextField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 9)
{
    if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)])
    {
           UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [textView inputAssistantItem];
          inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
          inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    }

}
```

This way it will also check for iOS9 as `UITextInputAssistantItem` is for iOS 9 only or you can simply keep this `if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)])` and no need for iOS 9 check